# Ruby on Rails: How to define a controller definition per shim?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, model-view-controller

First time asking something here on StackOverflow. So excited!

Basically, I'm wondering what the correct design pattern is for what I'm trying to accomplish.  I have all my code working but was wondering it there's a more elegant, "RoR Way" to put it all together. For a language/framework so beautiful, it just *feels* like I've done this wrong:

I have a single master layout page ("WeekSummary") I'm using to display a bunch of "DaySummary" shims. All shims derive from the same template "_day_summary.html.erb."

On WeekSummary, I'm able to pass variables to individual shims fairly easily, eg:

```
<%= render 'layouts/day_summary', date: '2016-08-12' %>
<%= render 'layouts/day_summary', date: '2016-08-11' %>
```

But now I'm having trouble invoking a "day_summary" controller definition per each shim. Essentially, at this point in the render lifecycle, I believe I've already passed through the "C" part when the RoR engine called my "week_summary" definition (in which I did hold some business logic). But now I want the RoR engine to *go back* to the controller and call a "day_summary" controller definition *per each shim* I've defined on WeekSummary view page. I would like all variables/definitions to be then locally scoped to each shim (so I can reuse the same var names, etc).

I wasn't able to figure out how to do that though so right now I've simply dumped all my shim-specific business logic at the top of the "_day_summary.html.erb" in a massive <% %> block. Having so much business logic there in a View shim seems wrong though.

I hope this made sense. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to properly do this?  Essentially, I'm trying to encapsulate the rendering of each shim into its own MVC lifecycle/pattern, if that makes sense.  Thank you!

**Edit: In response to kcdragon's code request on what's happening inside each shim:**
So, for example, for each day_summary shim, I wish to calculate that day's pnl.

At the top level, in the week_summary controller def, I get all transactions:

```
@transactions = Transaction.all.order('ticker', 'date DESC')
```

Then in each shim, I filter @transactions by only the date I care about for that shim. Thus, a sample of each shim's business logic includes the below-- in this example, calculating that day's PnL:

```
transactions = @transactions.where(date: '2016-08-08')
pnlHash = Hash.new
totalPnl = 0
transactions.each do |t|
  if !pnlHash.key?(t.ticker)
    pnlHash[t.ticker] = t.pnl 
  else 
    pnlHash[t.ticker] += t.pnl 
  end 
  totalPnl += t.pnl
end
```

<%= totalPnl %> is then rendered elsewhere on the shim.

There's other business logic too that happens in the shim, but this is a good representative sample.

Now, obviously at the top level (week_summary), I could "pre-process" all daily PnL calculations and then store them in some massive hashtable which I'd then use to extract values per day_summary shim. (In this example, I guess that'd be a *true* model of the week_summary view.) But I don't want to do that. I want to encapsulate day_summary into its own thing, where all its business logic and rendering is processed on the fly as week_summary renders. Hopefully that makes sense?

**Edit2: For sake of clarity, here's what each day_summary shim looks like. On the week_summary view, five of these guys are rendered, each one corresponding to its respective date:**

[Here's what the day_summary shim looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQlp0.png)

Comment: "dumped all my shim-specific business logic at the top of the "_day_summary.html.erb" in a massive <% %> block" - Can you post this logic? It will help with figuring out the best place for it to go.

Comment: @kcdragon -- Done. Per requested, I've posted a sample of the shim-specific "day_summary" business logic.  It's a small but representative snippet of what I'm doing within each day_summary shim.

Comment: i'm voting to close your question as it's primarily opinion based and thus it's not a question that fits into stackoverflows criterias.